# Can't call hook index document build

Tags: hooks, search

I have installed the **apachesolr** module and it all works fine.
To display more details about results, Ivs decided to add indexes.

But Im stucked, because the 
`hook_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id)` is not called.

Im using the last version of both **solr** and **Drupal module**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it.
The hook is called during the indexing not during the search.